# Why do we say that the electrostatic field around the point charge is a harmonic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

Generally speaking, the electrostatic field is an active field and an irrotational field. But why the field formed by electric intensity around the point charge is the harmonic field? (passive and irrotational).

Comment: Is this because it satisfies a Laplace equation?

Comment: Yes it is because they are solutions to laplaces equation which is a definition of a harmonic function.